# Neo4j browser storing cypher set value as long

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

In my embedded neo4j server I am storing some values as `Integer` types, which works fine. However if I view my database through the neo4j browser, any `set` command I use is setting the value type as `Long`, which renders type conversion errors from that point on. For example:

```
MATCH (a:`JOB` {id: "something"}) SET a.totalSubscribers = 0
```

It seems as though the `totalSubscribers` value gets set to type `Long`. Is there any way to set it to `Integer` through the neo4j browser? I have tried `toInt(0)`, but that doesn't change the result.

EDIT:

It seems as though incrementing or decrementing a property still causes the issue also. Eg.

```
a.totalSubscribers = a.totalSubscribers + 1
```